# Where to define common environment variables in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 4. I have a set of properties that is common for all environments such as dev, staging, prod etc. Where can I place those properties in angular 4?.
 
I have read about environments but there I have to copy the same properties to all environment files ie. `environment.ts`, `environment.prod.ts` etc.

Comment: Anywhere you want. You export them from a TypeScript file, and import them where you need them.

Comment: @JBNizet  Thanks. Is not possible with environment.ts?

Comment: environment.ts is designed for things that depends on the environment. You just have some constants, that don't depend on the environment. So define them anywhere you want, except in environment.ts.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new environment.common.ts file and then import it inside each of your environments files.

environment.common.ts

```
export const commonEnvironment = {
   property1: "value"
};
```

environment.ts and environment.prod.ts etc...

```
import { commonEnvironment } from './environment.common';

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  common: commonEnvironment
};
```

You have to use the common property to use your sub properties.