# How to use default values for Angular environments

Tags: angular, typescript

I have several environment files for my Angular application :

- environment.ts
- environment.dev.ts
- environment.prod.ts

I'd like to use default variables shared by all environments without duplicating them in every file.
If I add a variable 'homeUrl' only in **environment.ts** for example :

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://some-backend-url/',
  homeUrl: '/illustrator/directory'
};
```

When I run the application with the dev configuration, my variables from **environment.dev.ts** are loaded properly but homeUrl is undefined as it's only declared in **environment.ts** file.

Is there a way to use default variables shared between environments without copying them ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485087/where-to-define-common-environment-variables-in-angular-4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can import default variables from outside.

default.ts:

```
export const default = {
  apiUrl: 'http://some-backend-url/',
  homeUrl: '/illustrator/directory'
}
```

in environment.ts:

```
import {default} from 'default'

export const environment = {
  ...default,
  production: false
}
```

and import it in all files. So in this way you can modify only in default.ts file and will be apply automaticaly in all enviroments

Comment: And if I declare the variable in one of the environment files, will it override the default ones ?

Comment: This suggestion worked although I couldn't use 'default' as a name, thank you Oleg.

Comment: `'default'` is not allowed as name `ts(1389)` variable declaration. It is useful to be careful when naming.

Answer (score 3):

My answer will improve [Oleg answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791420/1283715):

**1. Base interface:**

```
// config.ts
export interface Config {
   production: boolean;
   apiUrl: string;
   homeUrl: string;
   // added other need config definition.
}
```

**2. Base environment:**

```
// environment.base.ts
export const environmentBase = {
  apiUrl: 'http://some-backend-url/',
  homeUrl: '/illustrator/directory'
  // add more base, default, share config definitions.
}
```

**3. Production environment:**

```
// environment.prod.ts
export const environment: Config = {
    ...environmentBase,
  production: true,
}
```

**4. Development environment:**

```
// environment.dev.ts
export const environment: Config = {
    ...environmentBase,
  production: false,
}
```

Comment: You need an environment.ts file or TypeScript will get cranky. Check the main.ts file and there will be a red squiggle.

Comment: Wanted to expand on my previous comment.

To resolve this, I created an environment.ts file and it's content is `export const environment = {} as IEnvironment;` (IEnvironment is just an interface I use to hard type the properties in my env file).

The ng build commands should overwrite this file with the correct env file. That needs to be specified. To do so, in angular.json, update the "fileReplacements" configurations to point to the right files.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to object spreading/assignment, you can just declare environment configs as a class that each inherit from your 'base' class.

```
// environment.ts
export class environment {
  static value = 'DefaultValue';
  static homeUrl = 'DefaultUrl';
}
```

then in your other environment configs...

```
// environment.dev.ts, environment.prod.ts...
import { environment as EnvironmentBase } from './environment';

export class environment extends EnvironmentBase {
  static newThing = '??';
  static homeUrl = 'NewUrl'; // overridden
}
```

Things to note: these are now classes instead of object literals, so their properties should be static to match access. Also, you'd need to import the base config as a different name since you're defining a class with the same name in that file (or just make a separate base class altogether)/

Comment: This solution will fail when try to access `environment` on appModule `,  ex. ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment. production})`, with 
_AppModule' Function calls are not supported in decorators new object_, **environment should export as const/var**, check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60442763/1283715).

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing myself seems more nifty to me so I'm sharing it here:

Basically I'm creating an Interface along with a class that holds my defualt values

```
//environment.model.ts

interface IEnvironment {
  production?: boolean;
  appBase?: string;
  name: string;
}

export class Environment {

  constructor(config: IEnvironment) {
    return Object.assign(this, config);
  }

  // default values
  production = true;
  appBase = '/';
  
  // readonly values
  readonly someToken = 'token';
}
```

So now in your environment file you can do this

```
export const environment = new Environment({
  production: false,
  name: "local",
});
```

This way:

- You can define **mandatory fields** in all your environment files (here it is `name`)
- You have **default values** for some fields and those are optional (here `production`, `appBase`)
- You also have **readonly fields** that can not be overwritten and stay the same between all your environments (`someToken`)